# wanted to add Validation in edittext fragment

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I wanted to add the validation in the Edittext. I am pasting some code.
Actually I wanted only simple validation like (the field can not be empty). I have created almost 10 edittext and 1 spinner.

```java
package com.example.ncaputtarakhand;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ComplainFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText Name, Mobile, Email, Adhar, ComplainRelated, Complain, Locality, Landmark, Pincode, Username;
    Button btn;
    Spinner spinner;

    DatabaseReference reff;
    Complain complain;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_complain, container, false);

        Name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        Mobile = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        Email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        Adhar = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.adhar);
        ComplainRelated = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.related);
        Complain = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.complainhere);
        Locality = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.location);
        Landmark = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.landmark);
        Pincode = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pincode);
        Username = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spin);
        btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonsend);

        complain = new Complain();
        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Complain");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                complain.setName(Name.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setNumber(Mobile.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setEmail(Email.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setAdharNo(Adhar.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setComplainRelated(ComplainRelated.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setComplain(Complain.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setLocality(Locality.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setLandmark(Landmark.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setPincode(Pincode.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setUsername(Username.getText().toString().trim());
                complain.setSpinner(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
                reff.push().setValue(complain);
                Toast.makeText(ComplainFragment.super.getContext(), "Complain Register Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spin);

        // Creating an Array Adapter to populate the spinner with the data in the string resources
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.locationn, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        ///database

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onClick` method to:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(inputIsValid()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

moving all of the current contents of that method into the curly brackets above.

Create your new method:

```
private boolean inputIsValid() {
    if(Email == null || Email.getText().toString().trim().length() < 7 || !EmailValidator.getInstance(false).isValid(Email.getText().toString().trim())) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please enter a valid email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    if(Username ... ) {
        Toast ...
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

which should only return `true` if ALL `EditText` contents are acceptable.

Go through the `EditText` one-by-one returning false if the contents aren't acceptable, after raising a `Toast` with the reason.

Comment: can you please show the toast line by example how to do .

Comment: sir i am sorry i am unable to understand the solution can you tell me just by 1 edittext example

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you the pattern of the `inputIsValid()` method. You just need to stick to this pattern going through each `EditText` one by one with the relevant checks.

Comment: Sir i am getting error on Toast.makeText(this, "please nenter valid", Toast.....). On (this) error cannot resolve method

Comment: One thing more sir can we use this in the fragment?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that this was a `Fragment`. I have replaced `this` with `getActivity()` as the first parameter in `makeText()`.

Comment: can you ellaborate what to change on onClick method

Comment: I have amended my answer for clarity.  All you need to do is wrap the existing `onClick` method in the conditional statement, so that when the button is clicked, the validation method is run and if the result is `true` then proceed with the method as you had written it.

Comment: can you tell me what is this EmailValidator its giving an error (cant resolve symbol)

Comment: It's from Apache Commons; see  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/index.html . Don't use it if you don't want to. I was just suggesting an approach to validating an email address. You could manually check for `@` and dot symbol positions if you'd prefer. But my answer was really just about code structure. I have no idea what validation checks you need.